# Convert Ansible command to pip task

Tags: pip, ansible

I'd like to convert the following to a Ansible pip task:

```
- name: install packages and setup profile 3
  shell: pip install --user vex
```

I do not see anything in the Ansible documentation for installing for user.

Comment: Have you tried using: `extra_args`?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Do you want to pass `vex` as a command line argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pip` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html) with `extra_args` parameter:

```
- name: install packages and setup profile 3
  pip:
    name: vex
    state: present
    extra_args: --user
```

Ansible passes the value given in the parameter directly to the `pip` command.